# ps utility in linux (procps), how to check which CPU is used

Tags: linux, ps, procps

It is about `procps` package, utility `ps` for linux.

Can it print the number of last used CPU for each process (thread)?

Update: Not a CPU Time (10 seconds), but a CPU NUMBER (CPU0,CPU5,CPU123)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

which of multiple processors? it does not offer an option for that according to the manpage. but on my Debian stable system it accepts the undocumented `-o cpu`

---

after looking at the source, and the output of `ps L`, I believe your answer is either the `cpuid` or `sgi_p` output options, column IDs CPUID and P, respectively.

---

And 'cpu' *should* work according to this note in output.c, but it's currently tied to the 'nop' output pr_nop():

`{"cpu",       "CPU",     pr_nop,      sr_nop,     3,   0,    BSD, AN|RIGHT}, /* FIXME ... HP-UX wants this as the CPU number for SMP? */`

Comment: no, it doesn't. Not a CPU time, but `Number of last used CPU` (CPU0,CPU1,CPU2) as it is in `top` "f" "j" `J: P          = Last used cpu (SMP)`

Comment: But `top` from same `procps` can.

Comment: I see that and agree. But there is no such option in ps as documented by the manpage.

Comment: aha! try -o cpu; it accepts it, but on my single-processor system only shows "-"

Comment: on my 4cpu system it is also `-` for all processes (

Comment: please see my latest edit, hopefully one of those options will serve your needs.

Answer (score 30):

The ps(1) man page says you can use the `psr` field:

> ```
>    psr        PSR     processor that process is currently assigned to.
> ```

```
$ ps -o pid,psr,comm
  PID PSR COMMAND
 7871   1 bash
 9953   3 ps
```

Or you can use the `cpuid` field, which does the same thing.

```
$ ps -o pid,cpuid,comm
  PID CPUID COMMAND
 7871     1 bash
10746     3 ps
```

The reason for two names is for compatibility with [Solaris](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS+5.7&format=html) (`psr`) and [NetBSD/OpenBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=NetBSD+5.0&format=html) (`cpuid`).

To get threads too, add the `-L` option (and the `lwp` field if you are using `-o`).

Without threads:

```
$ ps -U $USER -o pid,psr,comm | egrep 'chromi|PID' | head -4
  PID PSR COMMAND
 6457   3 chromium-browse
 6459   0 chromium-browse
 6461   2 chromium-browse
```

With threads:

```
$ ps -U $USER -L -o pid,lwp,psr,comm | egrep 'chromi|PID' | head -4
  PID   LWP PSR COMMAND
 6457  6457   3 chromium-browse
 6457  6464   1 chromium-browse
 6457  6465   2 chromium-browse
```

There's also an undocumented `-P` option, which adds `psr` to the normal fields:

```
$ ps -U $USER -LP | egrep 'chromi|PID' | head -4
  PID   LWP PSR TTY          TIME CMD
 6457  6457   3 ?        00:01:19 chromium-browse
 6457  6464   1 ?        00:00:00 chromium-browse
 6457  6465   2 ?        00:00:00 chromium-browse
```

Comment: There's also a `-P` option, which isn't documented, but saves some typing.

Answer (score 4):

Also much underrated:

```
mpstat -I ALL 1 | less -SR
```

You can add an iteration count (like `mpstat 1 1` for just one iteration).

To still have color terminal output, tell `mpstat`:

```
S_COLORS=always mpstat -I ALL 1 | less -SR
```

[image]

To have it statically updating on a terminal without scrolling:

```
watch -wcn .5 S_COLORS=always mpstat -I ALL 1 1
```

[image]

Comment: Is it available in old ubuntu?

Comment: It was already available in [Dapper (2006)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/sysstat) and lives in package `sysstat`. Haven't looked farther back though

Comment: For that matter, you can run `top` and press `1` (number 1) to see workload per CPU.

Comment: i have a 4-socket 96 core server, with `mpstat` and even `top 1` is there a way to just print a single snapshot output that I can scroll to see everything in the window?  My monitor is not big enough to resize a single window to see all 96.

Comment: @ron Just add the iteration count: `mpstat -I ALL -1 1 | less -SR` does the trick for me (look at me supporting random answers after 13 years :))

Comment: @ron Ooh, just realized that mpstat supports terminal colors now, so `S_COLORS=always mpstat -I ALL 1 1 | less -SR` is even better. Updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

I did it this way on Arch, it might help someone out there:

```
ps -C "process" -L -o pid,lwp,pcpu,cpuid,time
```

- **-C**: select the process named "process"
- **-L**: list the process threads
- **-o**: specify output info

  - *pid*: process id
  - *lwp*: light weight process (thread)
  - *pcpu*: CPU usage (percent)
  - *cpuid*: CPU id
  - *time*: thread time (from start)