# How to find all process running on a core

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am using Linux system which is having 8 core.
I am seeing from top command that core 0 is 100% used .

Please suggest how can I see real time usage of core 0 and all process running on core 0

Comment: Does this answer to your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732192/ps-utility-in-linux-procps-how-to-check-which-cpu-is-used

Comment: It is showing processes but not what I want . I want all process running on core 0

Answer (score 5):

[`ps`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) can show a list of processes. Pass `--sort=-pcpu`, to sort by cpu percent. `psr` shows processor that process is currently assigned to. [`watch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) allows to see how the list changes over time:

`watch -- ps -axo psr,pcpu,uid,user,pid,tid,args --sort=-pcpu`

Comment: This is only showing watch and ps command informationn in output